# MongoDb pull with positional operator

Tags: mongodb

I have the following structure for a document

```
{
 _id: 12342342
 items: [
   {
      ownerId: 123,
      dates: ['2014-10-01', '2014-10-02']
   },
   {
      ownerId: 234,
      dates: ['2014-10-01', '2014-10-02']
   },

 ]
}
```

I want to pull a specific value from dates where the ownerId of the parent object is a specific value.

I have

```
   var myDate = '2014-10-01'
   db.collection('things').update({'items.dates': {$in: [myDate]}}, 
      {$pull: { 'items.$.dates': myDate } }, {multi: true});
```

But this will pull for any ownerId, which is not what I want. Can someone help me get the right query syntax?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you want to **pull** on specific **ownerId**, you need to specify that **ownerId** in the query part of **update** method. This is a reference for you:

```
var myDate = '2014-10-01';
var ownerId = 123;

db.things.update({
    'items' : {
        '$elemMatch' : {
            ownerId : ownerId,
            dates : {
                $in : [ myDate ]
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $pull : {
        'items.$.dates' : myDate
    }
}, {
    multi : true
});
```

Actually, operator **$in** is unnecessary here.

```
var myDate = '2014-10-01';
var ownerId = 123;

db.things.update({
    'items' : {
        '$elemMatch' : {
            ownerId : ownerId,
            dates : myDate
        }
    }
}, {
    $pull : {
        'items.$.dates' : myDate
    }
}, {
    multi : true
});
```

Comment: how is $in unnecessary? dates is an array

Comment: @Jeff, the equality expression `{dates : myDate}` means dates itself is equal to myDate, or any element of dates (if dates is array type) is equal to myDate. Array type is relatively a little "complicated" in MongoDB. :)