# Mongoose $pull is deleting nested entire array instead of a single value in the array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo schema that looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58e4222497b2735ba3cd9ec4"),
"place" : "",
"plant" : "Test1",
"eventDate" : ISODate("2017-04-05T00:00:00Z"),
"event" : "Test123",
"toBeTested" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58e453a07c9f94702ebac93d"),
        "thingsTested" : [
            "A1",
            "A2",
            "A3"
        ]
    }
]}
```

I'm using mongoose to remove a single element of `thingsTested`. My code in mongoose is:

```
Layout
    .update(
        {_id: req.params.parentid}, 
        {$pull: {toBeTested: {thingsTested: 'A3'}}},
        function (err, docs){
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
            res.json(docs);    
        }
    );
```

As you can see, I've hardcoded that I want to remove `A3` from the `thingsTested` set. However, the exhibited behavior is that all of `thingsTested` is being deleted.

As a followup question, how can I make sure that the mongoose command only removes `A3` in `thingsTested` with the `_id` of `58e453a07c9f94702ebac93d` (the child ID)?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDb pull with positional operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319733/mongodb-pull-with-positional-operator)

Comment: nah, using a positional operator for this would be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to select an outer array element in your query, and then the matched element can be referenced with a `$`, like so:

```
//                                 ▼ selecting the toBeTested element
update({_id: req.params.parentid, 'toBeTested.thingsTested': 'A3'}, 
//                          ▼ referencing the selected element
       {$pull: {'toBeTested.$.thingsTested': 'A3'}}});
```

Comment: How would I add the reference to the specific `thingsTested` `_id` (`58e453a07c9f94702ebac93d`)?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean because the `thingsTested` elements in your sample data don't have an `_id` but I think you'd just have to put it in the query somewhere so that you're only matching documents that have that id. Maybe something like: `{_id: req.params.parentid, 'toBeTested.thingsTested': 'A3', 'toBeTested.thingsTested.A3._id': [id]}`. You can add as many parameters to the query as you want, it will only match documents that match all of them.

Comment: My apologies, I actually meant that `toBeTested` has an `_id`. But this is helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Just for clarification. You've used `$` positional operator in update part. You have to use `elemMatch` to match on more than one field i.e  `_id` and `thingsTested` in `toBeTested` array. `Layout.update({
    'toBeTested' : {
        '$elemMatch' : {
            "_id": ObjectId("58e453a07c9f94702ebac93d"),
            "thingsTested": "A3"
        }
    }
}, {
    $pull : {
        'toBeTested.$.thingsTested' : "A3"
    }
})
`. The query part will resolve the `$` to a index with matching element. In your case it will be 0 and update will use this index to pull the `A3` from array.